# How to use WebAPI post JSON values having "

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
 public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] bot bot)  
{
   string jsonstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bot);

   return jsonstr;
}
public class bot 
{
   public string bot_id { get; set; } 
   public string bot_uid { get; set; }             
}
```

Webapi post
JSON Params

```
{
    "bot_id":"XX"XX"
}
```

if json value has ", how can I create a model to post webapi?

Comment: JSON syntax dictates that double quotes inside strings needs to be escaped, ie. you should have `"XX\"XX"`. If you don't, then you simply don't have *legal* JSON and you should not expect any library to be able to deserialize/parse this properly.

Comment: what is mean by use webapi post json ? do you want to post your model class to api using c#?

Answer (score 0):

## If this is about returning values

If bot id has a double quote in it the json serializer will escape it and there should be no problems.

I suspect you may be misreading the json. Some tools<s>, including Visual Studio's Watch and Local Variables windows</s> and the console window may show escaped `"` without the backslash and it may appear as if the string is `{ "bot_id":"XX"XX" }` when in fact it's `{ "bot_id":"XX\"XX" }`.

Also, is it possible that `XX"XX` is `XX''XX` (with two single quotes)?

In either case `JsonCovert` will serialise the string correctly.

[image]

## If this is about consuming json

`{ "bot_id":"XX"XX" }` is a piece of invalid json.

I think there are two options here

### Fix json (preferred)

Ask the poster to fix their payload.

### Preprocess the json

You can accept json, fix known issues and only then feed it to the json deserialiser.

```
ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] string botJson)  // accept body as string
{
  string fixedJson = fixMyJson(botJson);
  var bot = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Bot>();
  ...
```

Or

```
async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post()
{
   HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
   string botJson = await requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

  string fixedJson = fixMyJson(botJson);
  var bot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bot>(fixedJson);
  ...
```

Comment: ...and the `fixMyJson()` will have to know about the possible error sources in senders json creation. Probably the sender should do her homework, not the receiver.

Comment: *Visual Studio* displays strings with escape sequences, confusing people that don't know about escape sequences. You'll find a lot of questions asking how to replace `\"` with `"`. `XX"XX` is what you get when printing out the string contents, eg with `Console.Write`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sure you're right - I genuinely don't remember which window / console display which. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: I don't even notice this myself, but I must be answering at least one such question every week